# Is there any way I can try to read files with suffix like '.sas7bdat', '.dta', '.sav' and '.xpt' by using JAVA？

Tags: java, spring-boot, import, sas, file-type

I am working on a module, which can import different kinds of files(currently those file types are SAS output format). Of course, this module is written by java, springboot. The main logic is that when user upload a file, the controller will pass the file inputstream to this module, and call the corresponding method by the file's suffix.
I have done some investigation and found that R-language and python could do this. Can anybody tell me whether there is another way, I mean, can do this job only by JAVA. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/epam/parso to read .sas7bdat files

Answer (score 0):

The sas7bdat is a binary, proprietary format. Its layout has never been made public. Some people have figured it out (like the parso mentioned in the comment). If you really want to go down this path, use the python library as a guide. It will help with sas7bdat and sas7bcat. For the old SAS transport format, see my library on GitHub which is in C#. The new transport format appears to have some incorrect information in its description on the SAS website which I couldn't get around. I have put my code on GitHub in case you want to try.

All that said, let me offer a few words of wisdom: don't do it. Use the python library vs doing it in Java. Also, these libraries read the format vs having read/write. Keep that in mind (it sounds like it doesn't matter but FYI).

Comment: can you show me your github library link address?

Comment: Here it is. I focus on working with SAS via .NET.  https://github.com/savian-net?tab=repositories

Comment: He could try to run the sas7bdat python module with jython or compile it with jython into java class.

Comment: thank you all of you, but my leader wants me to implement a java module to read those files. I am gonna be busy for quite a time.